# SQL Server Reporting Services VS rdlc and the ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, comparison, rdlc

We are planning on creating reports to be run on the same computer that the database application is running on.

Can you tell me which of these is the best approach? (SQL Server Reporting Services or creating a rdlc ReportViewer report)

Also I tried to locate detailed rdlc ReportViewer report tutorials both in books and online and found none. It's probably because I'm looking in the wrong places.

We are also using VB.Net as the language.

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, `.rdlc` is the client version. You cannot host these on the report server. These reports do not know how to fetch the data, you MUST get the data yourself and pass it to the report.  For this reason, you cannot even preview the report while designing. `ReportViewer.ProccessingMode = Local`

The `.rdl` or server reports know how to fetch the data. You configure the datasource and upload them to the report server. Because of this, you can preview the reports while designing them. You can use the web/desktop ReportViewer control to run the reports from inside your app...like a proxy between your application and the report server.`ReportViewer.ProccessingMode = Remote`

I prefer `rdl` for any sql datasource, but `rdlc` is also good for cases where your datasource is very complex or can only be built through the application code. I think there might be ways to configure an object datasource for `rdl` but I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you tell or show us where we can get detailed tutorials showing how to do both rdl and rdlc reports?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of any...I kinda learned by doing. Do you have the `Report Builder 3.0` desktop app for creating `rdl` reports? This might be a good start...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239338.aspx

Comment: The thing that confused me at first was VS2010 only created rdlc, I needed the separate Report Builder app to create the rdl.

Comment: So we can assume that using Report Builder 3.0 is the way to go. Can you show some VB.Net code that calls an rdl report from inside a VB.Net form passing parameters to it? Thanks again.

Comment: It's pretty simple, set the the `ReportPath = "/path/to/reportname"` and `ReportUrl = @"http<insert path>/reportserver"` properties on the ReportViewer's ServerReport prop. Call the SetParameter methods on said object. bingo bango done

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment. I'm currently reading SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services - Unleashed and made my first report. I think they also show how to integrate it like you described into the ReportViewer control.